# Can not get data attribute value from object in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple checkbox enclosed with container `div`

```
<div id="container">
<input type="checkbox" data-value="Apple" onclick="populateParent()" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-value="Orange" onclick="populateParent()" value="2"/>
...
</div>
```

Whenever user select the checkbox, I want to populate another select box with id and data-value. Here is the select box

```
<select name="parent_company" id="merge_parent"></select>
```

In `populateParent` function I can get the checkbox id, name, value etc. But I can't get the html5 data attribute. Here is the code:

```
function populateParent(){
var selectedCheckbox = $('#container').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
            return this;
   }).get();

 for(var i=0; i< selectedCheckbox.length; i++){
   var obj = selectedCheckbox[i];
  var option=
     '<option value="'+obj.id+'">'+obj.data('value')+'</option>';
                                        |- This throws Undefined error.

         output+=option;
      }
     $('#merge_parent').html(output);
    }
```

Instead of `obj.data('value')`, I have also tried using `obj.data-value` or `obj.attr('data-value')`. But, none of these are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use jquery function as obj already wrapped as DOM. Instead of using `.data()` or `.attr()`, try this native javascript code :

```
obj.getAttribute("data-value");
```

Comment: Thank you, Would you tell me, why `obj.data-value` or `obj.attr('data-value')` was not worked?

Comment: .attr() function is a jquery function and you can't use jquery function directly to access the DOM attribute/properties. Since you already wrapped `selectedCheckbox[i]` using array notation. After all, `obj.id` and `obj.name` also not jquery function. That why you can call get their id and name directly. Refer this link, hope this help. Sorry for my bad explanation. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_attributes.asp